# Python econding mail MIMEMultipart

Tags: python, html, email

So, this is code i have, took it from python.org, but when i send a email contaning special characters, such as "é" or "não", it shows up like this "Ã©" or "nÃ£o" on outlook.com, but other emails work fine.

Is there any way i can solve this? i tried setting .py encoding, html meta enconding but didnt work.

```
    copia = str(copia)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = assunto
    msg['From'] = de
    msg['To'] = para
    msg['Cc'] = copia           
    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    text = email_texto
    html = email_html

    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)


    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(de, self.senha)
    server.sendmail(de, (para, copia), msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Unicode Encoding (UTF-8). Here's an example:

http://www.askthepony.com/blog/2011/06/how-to-send-a-proper-unicode-encoded-email-using-python-2-7/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide example code in your answer, not only a link! Links may get broken over time ...

Comment: Well, it worked ok on outlook, but when i tested on gmail it didnt show anything at all